# How to change the status of the user using react-native-facebook-login

Tags: react-native

I installed `react-native-google-signin`. The function `GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync()` detects a change of the user's status when it is registered.

```
const user = GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync();
this.setState({user});
```

When I use `react-native-facebook-login`, how should I change the status of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two ways of using the package, one is to import the FBLogin button, the other is to create your own button and call the FBLoginManager. I am not 100% certain what do you mean by change the status of the user, but if you just want to set the state after user signs in, the idea is like this, very similar to your google code

```
FBLoginManager.loginWithPermissions(["email","user_friends"],(err, data) => {
  if (!err) {
    this.setState({user: data});
    this.props.onLogin(data.credentials); // whatever your logic is
  }
});
```

Here I am using the `FBLoginManager`, if you need a `FBLogin` example their document would be a perfect place to refer

https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login

Comment: Thank you very much!! Because I've come up with a new inconvenient using FCM-React native and at the same time react-native-google-sigin, I'm thinking of design in android studio using native language. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

To streamline your code, you could use a framework like [Invertase's React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase), which can handle Google, Facebook, and Twitter auth changes with the same API. Using this, you can just do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
        } else {
            // User has signed out
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Because I've come up with a new inconvenient using FCM-React native and at the same time react-native-google-sigin, I'm thinking of design in android studio using native language. What do you think?

Comment: I like Android Studio as a development environment. I think it some what you with your project. React Native gives you many things for free when developing and in many cases it speed up the delivery a lot. This is the reason why I have shifted more and more to React Native code.